# Add a viewcontroller's view to the bottom of a collectionview to scroll?

Tags: ios

I have a view that contains two view controllers. The first viewcontroller contains a collectionview (blue) whose frame takes up the entire view. Within this collectionview there are many objects that scroll (red squares). I want to add the second viewcontroller's view to the bottom of the collectionview such that everything scroll togethers as if they were all in the same collectionview. Is this possible?

Here is a picture of what I'm trying to do: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrWlG.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can design CollectionView like this:

- 2 section, first for all red squares, second for the another viewController's view
- in section 2,return a normal cell who add another viewController's view as subview.

  ```
  -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

      if (indexPath.section == 1) {
          UICollectionViewCell *cell = [[UICollectionView alloc] init];  //create a normal cell
          [cell addSubview:anotherVC.view];
          return cell;
      }
  }
  ```